# Replacing For Loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration

I am trying to replace for loops in Matlab.

```
 function A=ansatz(s,p,n)
 si(1:n+1)=2*((1:n+1)-1)/n-1;

 A(1,:)= s';
 for j=1:n+1
     for i=1:n+1
         A(j,i)=s(j)-si(i);
     end
 end

 A=ansatz([-1,-0.9,-0.7,0.6,1],2,4)
```

What i am trying to do is to fill the Matrix A with

```
s(1)-si(1)   s(1)-si(2)  ... s(1)-si(n+1)
s(2)-si(1)   s(2)-si(2)  ... s(2)-si(n+1)


s(n+1)-si(1)   s(n+1)-si(2)  ... s(n+1)-si(n+1)
```

Basicly the last two loops have to be replaced with vector iterations. All I accomplish is the first row.

```
A(1,:)= s(1)-si(1:n+1);
```

Anyone has a hint on how to iterate properly?
Edit: No for or while loops can be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun)

```
s = bsxfun(@minus, s(:), si(:).' )
```

---

If a loop must be used

```
for ii=1:numel(s)
    A(ii,:) = s(ii) - si(1:n+1);
end
```

---

No `bsxfun` and no loops (hands tied behind back, one eye shut, 3 books and a fork balanced over my head):

```
s = repmat( s(:), [1 n+1] ) - repmat( si(:).', [n+1 1] );
```

Comment: This works but an iteration of vector is what I am looking for.

Comment: @Paulinchen2 what exactly do you mean by "vector iteration" that is not a `for` or `while` loop?

Comment: Look at my last line of code.
A(1,:)= s(1)-si(1:n+1); Something like this for the whole matrix.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41202/discussion-between-paulinchen2-and-shai)